# Analytics for Apache Hadoop launch fails with ssl_error_weak_server_ephemeral_dh_key

Tags: analytics, ibm-cloud, analytics-for-hadoop, analytics-for-apache-hdp

I created service for Analytics for Apache Hadoop and while launching it fails with SSL error

[image: SSL error message while launching]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue after last Firefox upgrade.

Temporal workaround from [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1066238):

1. In FireFox, enter "about:config" in the URL field and press enter.
2. Accept the "This might void your warranty!" warning :)
3. In the search field at the top, enter "security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes"
4. Double click each result (128 and 256) to toggle the Value to
   "false"

Now retry your site - it should work now.  Remember to change these settings back when you're done.

Other possible workaround is using Chrome while servers are upgraded.

Comment: I tried with the steps already still i am facing the same issue in Firefox but switching the browser works