# Using Firefox on Mac to launch Analytics for Apache Hadoop and receive Secure Connection Failed

Tags: security, connection, ibm-cloud, analytics-for-hadoop, analytics-for-apache-hdp

Using Firefox on Mac to launch Analytics for Apache Hadoop and receive Secure Connection Failed: An error occurred during a connection to bi-hadoop-prod-2215.services.dal.bluemix.net:9443

Comment: Using stackoverflow on internet to launch guys brain for guessing my question and receive answer failed : an error occured during transcription dze.dzemm.0712DZEP.ccom.:120378

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738770/analytics-for-apache-hadoop-launch-fails-with-ssl-error-weak-server-ephemeral-dh